# Javafx/application not found Gradle JavaFX

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

When I run my code in Intellij, it runs perfectly fine. When I build the gradle project and get the jar, that works great too. However, when I try to run that jar I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:821)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:719)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:642)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:600)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        at classes.Main.main(Main.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 10 more
```

Here is my gradle build

```
    plugins {
    id 'groovy'
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.9'
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(14))
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:19.0.0'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20090211'
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '30.0-jre'
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '3.17'

}

javafx {
    version = "15.0.1"
    modules = ["javafx.controls", "javafx.fxml", "javafx.swing"]
}

version = '1.0'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'classes.Main',
        )
    }
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest.from jar.manifest
    classifier = 'all'
    from {
        configurations.runtime.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    } {
        exclude "META-INF/.SF"
        exclude "META-INF/.DSA"
        exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"
    }
    with jar
}

artifacts {
    archives fatJar
}
```

This method of building the jar previously worked for my rest server application, no luck here though. Am I going about this wrong?

Comment: You need to add a [Class-Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) header to the `attributes` of the `manifest`. It needs to point to the JavaFX JAR files.

Comment: First, if you're trying to create a fat/uber JAR then check out the [Shadow plugin](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/introduction/). Second, a fat/uber JAR containing JavaFX will place JavaFX on the class-path which, while [technically not supported](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8256362), is apparently still currently workable; the only stipulation is your main class _cannot_ be assignable to `javafx.application.Application`. You'll have to launch JavaFX from a separate main class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the dependency:

```
javafx:javafx.controls:11.0.0
```

Comment: The JavaFX dependencies are already added by the `javafx { ... }` block (as part of the JavaFX Gradle plugin).